# parse JSON manually

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I need to parse a JSON string such as that shown below:

```
var json = 
"{\
foo: {\
  bar: 'something',\
  baz: {\
    jack: 'other',\
    jill: 5\
  },\
  bob: {\
    bill: 'hello',\
    bilbo: 11,\
      baggins: {\
        fizz: 'buzz'\
      }\
    }\
  }\
}";
```

I can't use `eval` or a JS library to parse this into a JavaScript object. All I have available to me are the methods of String, Object, etc.

The result of the parsing should be a JS object whose properties correspond to those of the JSON. The values of the JSON properties will only ever be numbers string or other objects, i.e. no arrays.

I'm really struggling with this, so if anyone could help me get started (or already has a completely solution), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Recent browsers provide `JSON`. What is the context of this? Why no libraries? Have a look at the `json2.js` implementation: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: This seems a completely pointless task. Even json2.js uses `eval`.

Comment: Uh, it's homework guys. Thats why he can't use the native JSON stuff.

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON; the names of object name/value pairs need to be strings. And the backslash-line-break is also not allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: @Gumbo The names don't need to be strings.  Go try it, you'll see.  The backslash line-break is a hack that works in some browsers but I would agree in saying it's not something that should be relied on.  However, if this is homework, moot point.

Comment: @Endophage: You’re wrong. In JSON, the names must be strings (see syntax diagram on [json.org](http://json.org) or [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.2)). And a backspace in JavaScript strings must not be followed by a line terminator (see [string literals syntax in the ECMAScript specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.4)).

Comment: @Endophage: What *your* browser accepts is something completely different.

Comment: @Gumbo: If I'm readying it correctly, it does appear that [ECMAScript5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.8.4) allows for the line continuation via a backslash: *LineContinuation ::
\ LineTerminatorSequence* Naturally the newline is not part of the string, but is an invisible character only for the sake of continuation.

Comment: ...Reading ES3, I have a feeling that the point they were trying to make was that you cannot enter a newline *into the string* by preceding a *LineTerminator* with a backslash, and simply didn't directly address the possibility of the backslash as a LineContinuation.

Comment: @patrick dw: Yes, it was added in Version 5 but is not valid in strict mode.

Comment: @Gumbo: Just tested in "strict mode" using Firefox 4, and it seems fine. Of course it could be an implementation failure. Any chance you have a reference?

Comment: @patrick dw: I think I’ve just misread something: “A Use Strict Directive may not contain an *EscapeSequence* or *LineContinuation*.” I’ve read something like “In strict mode […] may not contain an *EscapeSequence* or *LineContinuation*.” which is kind of nonsense.

Comment: @Gumbo: Ah yes, the `"use strict";` directive itself may not contain...

Comment: @Gumbo you can say what you like and present me with any specifications you want but jQuery doesn't use strings (line 91 onwards, I'm not confusing it with the var declaration at the top http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) for names and it doesn't make sense to.  The names are object scope variables.  How often have you escaped the name of a variable?

Comment: @Endophage: JSON is not JavaScript and vice versa. JSON is a data-interchange format and JavaScript is a programming language. What you are referring to is an object literal notation in JavaScript, but it’s not JSON. jQuery is written in JavaScript but not in JSON. `{foo:"bar"}` is valid JavaScript but it’s invalid in JSON as `foo` needs to be quoted as well.

Comment: @Gumbo interesting, well that clears up a couple of things for me.  I wish that JSON didn't stand for JavaScript Object Notation in that case...  Gave me crossed signals.

Comment: @Endophage: You're certainly not the first. The decision to call it "*JavaScript* Object Notation" likely helped in its acceptance and popularity, but certainly created a world of confusion as well!

Comment: @patrick dw it's as much the "Object Notation" as "JavaScript" that makes it confusing...  They could have called it "JavaScript Information Notation" or something like that and it would have at least made it clear it's not related to Objects... and it would have been pronounced almost the same :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var json = Function("return {\
foo: {\
  bar: 'something',\
  baz: {\
    jack: 'other',\
    jill: 5\
  },\
  bob: {\
    bill: 'hello',\
    bilbo: 11,\
      baggins: {\
        fizz: 'buzz'\
      }\
    }\
  }\
}")(); // object
```

Comment: `Function` accepts any valid JavaScript code but not “just” JSON.

Comment: +1 Clever, but of course unsafe and only *technically* not using `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon phihag's answer, I just made this up. It might be a start for you.

It does not support:

- Spaces outside key/value
- Any of `,{}:"` as key/value
- Arrays
- No error handling
- (Probably more - I haven't tested this extensively)

The code:

```
var json = '{"a":{"b":"test"},"c":123,"d":{"nested":{"key":null}}}';

var split = function(str, delimiter, func) {
    var res = [];
    var before = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(str[i] === delimiter) {
            if(func(str, i) === true) {
                res.push(str.substring(before, i));
                before = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    res.push(str.substring(before));
    return res;
};

var amountbefore = function(str, pos, character) {
    var amount = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if(str[i] === character) {
            amount++;
        }
    }
    return amount;
};

var parse = function(obj) {
    var stripped = obj.slice(1, -1);
    var splitted = split(stripped, ",", function(str, i) {
        return amountbefore(str, i, "{") === amountbefore(str, i, "}");
    });
    var res = {};
    if(stripped === "") return res;
    for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        var spl = split(splitted[i], ":", function(str, i) {
            return amountbefore(str, i, "{") === amountbefore(str, i, "}")
        });
        var val;
        if(spl[1][0] === "n")     val = null;
        if(/^\d/.test(spl[1][0])) val = spl[1] - 0;
        if(spl[1][0] === "\"")    val = spl[1].slice(1, -1);
        if(spl[1][0] === "{")     val = parse(spl[1]);
        res[spl[0].slice(1, -1)] = val;
    }
    return res;
};

parse(json); // parses the JSON string
```

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, JSON is very easy to parse: Just write parsing functions for each [construct](http://json.org). For example, here's one that parses `null`:

```
function parseNull(input, position) {
    if (input.substr(position, 4) != "null") throw "Cannot parse as null";
    return {result:null, position: position+4};
}
```

Implement a similar function for each construct, i.e. `parseString`, `parseArray`, `parseObject`, ... .

Given these functions, write a function `parse` that skips white-space and decides which of the above functions to call based on the first non white-space character. If that's `n`, call `parseNull`, if `{`, call `parseObject` etc. . Note that `parseArray` and `parseObject` will call `parse` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There may be reasons to use a custom JSON parsing method but in case this was what you were looking for...

JavaScript has this all built in for you.

Here's an example:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"myKey":"myValue"}');

console.log(json); // {myKey:'myValue'}
```